# How to print an ascii square spiral to the console

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, pattern-matching

This was an interview question that I couldn't figure out..

Print out the following output to the JavaScript console (or whatever console you use)

My attempt to solve this was to build an array of stars, and an array of spaces.

Then to print each line one by one modifying it by adding a star or changing a star to a space.

But this does not build the whole spiral. It only builds the top half, so I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution?

It feels like some sort of a recursive function would be good for this?

```
var starLine = [];
var spaceLine = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
    starLine.push('*');
    spaceLine.push(' ');
}

console.log(starLine.join(' '));
for (var i = 1; i <= 32/2; i+=2) {
    spaceLine[(i-1)] = '*';
    spaceLine[32-(i-1)] = '*';
    starLine[i] = ' ';
    starLine[32-(i)] = ' '; 
    console.log(spaceLine.join(' '));
    console.log(starLine.join(' '));
}
```

Edit: My attempt at a recursive solution. I got pretty close, but it's still somewhat hacky:
https://jsfiddle.net/6fa9uty3/

```
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *      
    *                                                               *      
    *   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   *      
    *   *                                                       *   *      
    *   *   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   *   *      
    *   *   *                                               *   *   *      
    *   *   *   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *                                       *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *                               *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   * * * * * * * * * * * * *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *                       *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *   * * * * * * * * *   *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *               *   *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   * * * * *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *       *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *   * * *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   *           *   *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *   * * * * * * *   *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *   *                   *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *   * * * * * * * * * * *   *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   *                           *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   *                                   *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   *   *   *      
    *   *   *   *                                           *   *   *      
    *   *   *   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   *   *      
    *   *   *                                                   *   *      
    *   *   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   *   *  
    *   *                                                           *   *  
    *   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   *  
    *                                                                   *  
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

(Image in case text doesn't render properly)
[image: square spiral]

Answer (score 1):

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/oc5b5qzh/ - View console window in browser to see the spiral.

Keep size odd. I used different letters instead of * for each case just so you could see what part of the loop solved that case. Could obviously be compressed more, but that would just make it less readable.

Note: Doesn't match what you have exactly. I think mine spirals the other direction.

```
var size = 21;

for (var h = 0; h < size; h++) {
    var line = "";
    for (var w = 0; w < size; w++) {
        if (h < size/2) {
            if (h % 2 === 0) {
                if (w >= h && w < size - h) {
                    line += "A";
                }
                else {
                    line += (w % 2 === 0) ? "B" : " ";
                }
            }
            else {
                if (w >= h && w < size - h) {
                    line += " ";
                }
                else {
                    line += (w % 2 === 0) ? "C" : " ";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (h % 2 === 0) {
                if (w < h - 1 && w >= size - h) {
                    line += "D";
                }
                else {
                    line += (w % 2 === 0) ? "E" : " ";
                }
            }
            else {
                if (w < h - 1 && w >= size - h) {
                    line += " ";
                }
                else {
                    line += (w % 2 === 0) ? "F" : " ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a python solution [**pixelscan**](https://github.com/dpmcmlxxvi/pixelscan) that can traverse pixels in a variety of spatial patterns, including square rings like you have. The basic idea is move pixel-to-pixel in one of the 8 cardinal directions while maintaining a particular metric constant per ring, in your case it is the chebyshev metric.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it similar to iterating over a matrix in a spiral.

This is Python but it's trivial to understand the JavaScript equivalent.

```
def spiral(n):

  out = []
  for i in range(0, n):
    line = []
    out.append(line)
    for x in range(0, n):
      line.append(' ')

  x_start = 0
  y_start = 0
  x_stop = n
  y_stop = n

  while x_stop >= x_start:
    for x in range(x_start, x_stop):
      out[y_start][x] = '*'

    for y in range(y_start + 1, y_stop):
      out[y][x_stop - 1] = '*'

    y_start += 2

    for x in range(x_stop - 1, x_start, -1):
      out[y_stop - 1][x] = '*'

    y_stop -= 1
    x_start += 1

    for y in range(y_stop - 1, y_start - 1, -1):
      out[y][x_start] = '*'

    x_stop -=2
    y_stop -= 1
    x_start += 1

  for y in range(0, n):
    print(''.join(out[y]))
```

[See it](https://repl.it/FBtn/1).